# Defining/nesting modules and classes in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, module

I'm trying to define a variety of modules/classes in a Rails app. My directory structure looks something like this:

```
lib/
  fruit/ # just a module, with no associated file
    fruit_operator.rb
    apple.rb # abstract class, defines behavior for inheritance
    orange.rb # abstract class, defines behavior for inheritance
    apple/ 
      granny_smith.rb # should inherit from apple.rb
      red_delicious.rb
    orange/
      valencia.rb
      seville.rb
```

I want two things:

1. The sub-classes should inherit from their parent classes (Apple and Orange).
2. I should be able to access these classes from a top-level (within `/fruit` file -- ie `fruit_operator.rb`

All the attempts I've tried to get this working are throwing an error of some sort or another.

**Attempt # 1:**

*apple.rb*

```
module Fruit
  class Apple
    def juicy
      true
    end
  end
end
```

*apple/granny_smith.rb*

```
module Fruit
  class GrannySmith::Apple
  end
end
```

When I try to access `GrannySmith` from `fruit_operator.rb` I run into errors. Accessing as simply `GrannySmith` generates

```
uninitialized constant Fruit::FruitOperator::GrannySmith
```

If I try `Fruit::GrannySmith`, I get

```
uninitialized constant Fruit::GrannySmith
```

If I try `Apple::GrannySmith` or `Fruit::Apple::GrannySmith`, I hit the error

```
Unable to autoload constant Fruit::Apple::GrannySmith, expected /lib/fruit/apple/granny_smith.rb to define it
```

**Attempt #2:**

*apple.rb*

```
class Fruit::Apple
  def juicy
    true
  end
end
```

*apple/granny_smith.rb*

```
class GrannySmith < Fruit::Apple
end
```

Attempting to access from `fruit_operator.rb`, I run into identical errors as the above.

**Attempt #3:**

*apple.rb*

```
class Fruit::Apple
  def juicy
    true
  end
end
```

*apple/granny_smith.rb*

```
class Fruit::Apple::GrannySmith
end
```

This last version allows me to access the class directly from `fruit_operator.rb` (as `Apple::GrannySmith`), but it doesn't inherit from `Apple`!

Any idea how to structure/access these classes and modules? I've looked around quite a bit (on SO and elsewhere), and can't find a great guide for how to do this, particularly in a Rails app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must import the definition of the fruit files into the fruit operator file. For example,

```
require_relative './apple/granny_smith'
```

Comment: This was the way that worked for me. Thanks! I ended up requiring the whole apple tree like so: `Dir["./apple/*.rb"].each {|file| require_relative file }`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're best solution is to implement `Fruit` as a class, and have `Apple` and `Orange` both inherit from `Fruit`, and `GrannySmith` inherit from `Apple`, like so:

```
Class Fruit
  def seeds?
    true
  end
end

Class Apple < Fruit
  def juicy
    true
  end
end

class GrannySmith < Apple
  def color
    "green"
  end
end
```

Depending on what your need for the `fruit_operator` is, you may choose to `include` those methods/actions via a mixin `Module`.